# query receber valor de outra query

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Existe uma forma de uma TIBQuery receber a outra TIBQuery. Por exemplo:

```
Query1.Close;
Query1.Open;
Query2 := Query1;
if Query2Valor1.... // segue a lógica
```

Comment: Confirmando o que você quer: Uma query receber os dados da outra query? Ou os TFields? SQL?

Comment: Uma query receber os dados de outra Query.

Comment: @TiagoCasanova normalmente um componente recebe TUDO do outro se for da mesma classe. Ou seja, esse seu exemplo já deveria funcionar!

Comment: Não funciona o Query2Valor1 por exemplo não traz valor algum.

Comment: @JúniorMoreira Entendo que o código exemplificado pelo Tiago faz apenas a Query2 apontar na memória para a Query1, mas a Query2 não recebe os dados da Query1.  
Com essa tecnologia (**IB**) a realidade é o que respondi abaixo...

Comment: é o que o @Andrey disse, ele pode ainda pegar os valores por meio do método `FieldByName()` já que o `TFields` não é copiado (como  já mencionado Query2 só referencia a Query1, ela não é uma cópia)... o método `Assign()` se implementado faz a cópia, ou seja cria um nova referência... mas isso se a classe `TIBQuery` a implementar

Answer (score 1):

Com o `IB` acredito não ser possível.
Já com o *FireDAC* é possível por meio do `TFDDataSetReference`, no qual você pode passar a propriedade `data` de um *dataset* para outro do seguinte modo:
`FDQuery2.Data := FDQuery1.Data;`

Mas voltando para sua realidade, seria possível ainda passar o conteúdo da *TIBQuery* para um *ClientDataSet* por meio de *DataSetProvider*.
Não sei se é aceitável para sua necessidade, mas eu uso bastante esse recurso acima mencionado.